# Geopandas Points within Polygon; Is there a method to convert bool series result into a python list?

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

Working in Linux OS with Visual Studio Code; Jupyter Notebook module.

```
import geopandas as gpd
ubp1 = "/media/rg/data/map/urban boundary.geojson"
poly1 = gpd.read_file(ubp1)

import shapely.speedups
shapely.speedups.enable()

inUrban = gdf.within(poly1.loc[0, 'geometry'])
```

I'd like to manipulate the bool result so I have converted the pandas series to a Python list.

```
s = list(inUrban)
```

I tried this:

```
urban = []
dex = 0
for i in s:
    if s[dex] == "True":
        urban[dex] = 2
    else:
        urban[dex] = 0
    dex=+1
```

but that resulted in error:

```
IndexError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-ecba01b18d72> in <module>
      8         urban[dex] = 2
      9     else:
---> 10         urban[dex] = 0
     11     dex=+1

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is raised when you try to assign a value to an index position which doesn't exist in `urban` list.

You can use `append()` to solve this error.

```
urban = []
dex = 0
for i in s:
    if s[dex] == "True":
        urban.append(2)
    else:
        urban.append(0)
    dex=+1
```

A better way to solve this error would be to use the following:

```
urban = [ 2 if v == "True" else 0 for v in s ]
```

Comment: Thank you. Both suggestions worked after I removed the double quotes around True as it is bool type. I like your second suggestion. I will have to learn more about that concept.